# How to keep a log of execution in datastage?

Tags: etl, jobs, datastage

good afternoon

I've been searching the net how to do this but I can not find the solution:

I want to keep records of execution of each of the jobs in flat files.

Any idea how to do this??

I am using DataStage 8.5

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by invoking dsjob command from the command line in unix. dsjob has a lot of options like logsum etc using which you may redirect the output to a flat file in unix. Not sure how this could be done in windows though